# Omnifaces Socket should store notifications during lifecycle (socket is not connected yet)

Tags: sockets, jsf, push, omnifaces

I want to send/store push notifications to clients, which are currently not connected. My problem is that I have asynchronous ejb methods which should send those notifications. I invoke those methods in the url-action (prettyfaces)

When the page load needs more time than the asynchronous ejb method, the client will not be notified.

Does anyone have design hints, to store notifications until the client is not connected? Or can I configure this with the current implementation of `o:socket`?

e.g.: TestPage.java
message 02 will not be sent.

```
@Inject
private TestService testService;

@Inject
@Push
private PushContext someChannel;

@URLAction(onPostback = false, mappingId = TEST_ID)
public void urlAction() {
    test();
}

public void test() {
    // arg1: message; arg2: time to wait; arg3: consumer
    testService.doSomething("Message 01", 5000l, message -> someChannel.send(message));
    testService.doSomething("Message 02", 0l, message -> someChannel.send(message));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

TestService.java

```
@Stateless
public class TestService implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3755154079798713024L;

    @Asynchronous
    public void doSomething(String message, Long sleep, Consumer<String> callback) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        callback.accept(message);
    }
}
```

test.xhtml

```
<script>
function someSocketListener(message, channel) {
    alert(message);
}
</script>
<o:socket onmessage="someSocketListener" channel="someChannel" scope="view" />
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="#{testPage.test()}" >
        <f:ajax />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```